# How to route to Angular 2 component from Angular 1 app?

Tags: angular, angularjs-routing

So I have Angular 1 app. And I have Angular 2 component; let's say Heroes Dashboard, dashboard.component.ts from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial.

In Angular 2 router specified as list of:

```
{
    path: 'issue',
    component: FleetsComponent
}
```

In current Angular 1 app router paths are specified with url (ok, that would be "path"), template (ok, will specify path to html), and controller. 
What should I set in controller parameter?

Comment: Please post some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, ideally a Plunker.